# Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in pattern matching

Tags: f#

So, I'm doing an assignment where I'm supposed to write a function that prints an image based on some a type, figure, which I have defined.

I'm to use this library and it's functions with my own .fsx file, which should then be compiled and able to create images, based on a descriptive "figure"-type ;
https://github.com/diku-dk/img-util-fs

My .fsx code looks like this;

```
type point = int * int

type color = ImgUtil.color

type figure =
    | Circle of point * int * color
    | Rectangle of point * point * color
    | Mix of figure * figure



let rec colorAt (x,y) figure =
    match figure with
        | Circle ((cx,cy), r, col) ->
            if (x-cx)*(x-cx)+(y-cy)*(y-cy) <= r*r
            then Some col else None
        | Rectangle ((x0,y0), (x1,y1), col) ->
            if x0 <=x && x <= x1 && y0 <= y && y <= y1
            then Some col else None
        | Mix (f1, f2) ->
            match (colorAt (x,y) f1, colorAt (x,y) f2) with
                |(None , c) -> c
                |(c, None) -> c
                |(Some c1, Some c2) ->
                    let (a1 ,r1 ,g1 ,b1) = ImgUtil.fromColor c1
                    let (a2 ,r2 ,g2 ,b2) = ImgUtil.fromColor c2
                    in Some(ImgUtil.fromArgb ((a1+a2)/2, (r1+r2)/2,
                                              (g1+g2)/2, (b1+b2)/2))



let figTest : figure =
    Circle ((50,50), 45, ImgUtil.fromRgb(255,0,0))
    Rectangle ((40,40), (90,110) ImgUtil.fromRgb (0,0,255))



let makePicture (name:string * x:figure * b:int * h:int) : unit =
    let C = ImgUtil.mk b h
    for i = 0 to h
        do ImgUtil.setLine (ImgUtil.fromRgb(128,128,128)) (0,i) (b,i) C
    for n = (0,0) to (b-1,h-1) do
        match ImgUtil.getPixel n C with colorAt n x
            | None -> (128,128,128)
            | Some col -> colorAt n x
do imgUtil.toPngFile ("%A" name) C

do makePicture ("figTest" figTest 101 151)
```

But when I try to compile the library and my .fsx file I get the error
"8io.fsx(44.13): error FS0010: Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in pattern matching. Expected '->' or other token"

I'm fairly new to coding, and my code might not be usable, but it's the only compiling error I get, so I hope it's salvageable

Comment: There are many compile errors here, even if you fix the first one. Usually it wouldn't be possible for code to get into this state if you constantly monitor the errors provided by your editor. I would recommend starting again from scratch. You can copy small pieces of the code that you already have into your new code but make sure that you fix compile errors straight away rather than letting them build up. If you're not getting immediate feedback on compiler errors in your editor then stop everything and fix that first.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you're asking about is caused by this construct:

```ml
match ImgUtil.getPixel n C with colorAt n x
    | None -> (128,128,128)
    | Some col -> colorAt n x
```

The problem here is that `colorAt n x` appears unexpectedly between the `with` and the first `|`. A typical `match` expression should look more like this:

```ml
match ImgUtil.getPixel n C with
    | None -> (128,128,128)
    | Some col -> colorAt n x
```

Note: I haven't examined your code for correctness. This only addresses the specific syntactical issue identified by the compiler.